# Setting UILabel - Font through code - generates error - iPhone

Tags: iphone, uilabel, uifont

See following code carefully. Because it works perfectly. Try to add in your application. it will work

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// title label - tip
UILabel *tmp=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200)]; 
tmp.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(14.0/255.0) green:(105.0/255) blue:(128.0/255) alpha:1.0];
[tmp setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18]]; tmp.text=@"sagar";
tmp.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; [self.view addSubview:tmp]; [tmp release];
}
```

Now, see following code carefully. Because it doesn't work. See there is nothing difference between both of these code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// title label - tip
UILabel *tmp=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200)]; 
tmp.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(14.0/255.0) green:(105.0/255) blue:(128.0/255) alpha:1.0];
[tmp setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Black" size:18]]; tmp.text=@"sagar";
tmp.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; [self.view addSubview:tmp]; [tmp release];
}
```

I have just mentioned #Arial Black# instead #Arial# .

- However it isn't working.
- Is it because of iPhone doesn't support =Arial Black= ?

I would like to know why it isn't working.

How many different kind of font does iPhone support?

Is there any list?

How to set a font name to a UILabel or to any control ? (font which has space within there name )

Thanks in advance for sharing your knowledge with me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Here](http://iosfonts.com) is a list of fonts available in the iPhone OS. It would seem Arial Black is not among them.

Answer (score 12):

Try `@"Arial-BoldMT"`

Besides, you could always make yourself a list of available fonts:

```
for( NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames] ) {
  for( NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName] ) {
    NSLog(@"%@", fontName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of font apps in the App Store to see all the fonts - one of which is [iFonts](http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=oeISpovHE3k&offerid=146261.392614957&type=2&subid=0), an app I developed so I could email the list of fonts to someone else on the team.