# How can I change the font of a label programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, fonts, uilabel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting UILabel - Font through code - generates error - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380490/setting-uilabel-font-through-code-generates-error-iphone)

I want to know is there any way to set the font of a label programmatically as I need to change the font in my app when a condition is set true. How can I do so using Apple's variety of fonts?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1380490/730701) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1302833/730701).

Comment: take a quick look at **[UILabel Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html)**, I hope I did't say any new things with it...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make yourself a list of available fonts:

```
for( NSString *strFamilyName in [UIFont familyNames] ) {
  for( NSString *strFontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:strFamilyName] ) {
    NSLog(@"%@", strFontName);
  }
}
```

Now `set Font` `like` this:

```
 [yourLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"your font name here" size:fontsizehere]];
```

**EDIT** :

For example like this:

```
 [yourLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15]];
```

Comment: [Deja vu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1380548/730701)?

Answer (score 1):

Here use this code.

```
[labelname setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"American Typewriter" size:18]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Set like this

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:20];
    [label setFont:font];
```

Answer (score 1):

//set label

```
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Calibri" size:15];
```

//set label color

```
label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

//set label colr if you have RGB value

```
label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:180.0/255.0 green:6.0/255.0 blue:47.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```